# Cant Override onCreateView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello im trying to use fragments and i get compile error when overriding onCreateView.

If i remove the override the fragment view wont get created.

I have another fragment in another class that do compile with override over onCreateView so my problem is no JDK version

I think its something with the imports but i tried to delete all the import and to import them again.

My error code:

```
he method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type addRoutine.FavrotieExerciseFragment must override or implement a supertype method
```

This is my code:

```
    public class FavrotieExerciseFragment extends Fragment {

    public FavrotieExerciseFragment()
    {}

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_from_list, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You should show us your import statements. I'm also going to suggest making `FavrotieExerciseFragment` a `public static class` since Fragments should not be tied to an enclosing class instance.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was wrong import of LayoutInflater