# How to set button's setOnClickListener correctly?

Tags: android, button

I try to run with the following code and it broken.

I add a button and a listener but failed to run.

The running image is like this.

If I comment the listener it works,but without function of button click.

[image]

My java:

```
package com.example.btn_test4;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }


        Button mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

My fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.btn_test4.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="onClick和onLongClick事件" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Comment: please always provide the logcat output of the error, that surely could be helpful! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing `button1` from `fragment_main.xml` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity_main` and getting button1 from  `activity_main` layout.

So use `button` in `onCreateView` method of fragment.

For example

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

         Button mButton1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: @PankajKumar Thanks bro,So it may help others also.

Comment: It tells me I should remove @Override notation. I can't compile with this code.

Comment: @sam where did you write onCreateView function?

Comment: @sam see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621049/cant-override-oncreateview-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your Button is the part of fragment_main.xml, move your code to button and click listener inside the onCreateView of the fragment.

For Example.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
                    Button mButton1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
            return rootView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`button1` is the part of `fragment_main.xml`, move your code of button and click listener inside the `onCreateView` of the fragment.

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        Button mButton1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I remove MainActivity file or add a class named PlaceholderFragment? Thank you~

Comment: @sam you already have `PlaceholderFragment` class in your `MainActivity` just move the `button` code of `onCreate` to `onCreateView()` of your `PlaceholderFragment` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToast);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
        });

    }

}
```

and the layout xml files:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.btn_test4.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonToast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Toast" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What I'm see of your code is adding a line and changing button name. That's doesn't help to solve my problem. After test, the problem is still the same...

Comment: try to down load desktop top sharing from google chrome browser by going to APPS and download there...

Answer (score 0):

Hello try with this code:
     mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

}
});

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        Button mButton1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 }

}
```

Comment: It says: Duplicate nested type PlaceholderFragment